# Unable to establish connection between 2 JFrame

Tags: java, server, jframe, connection

I created a simple chat system between 2 JFrames and when running each one alone everything is working but to pass values from JF1 to JF2, this method is used:

```
public static void showClient(){
        chat_client client = new chat_client();
        client.setVisible(true);
        client.setPublicKey(generatedPublicKey);
        client.setPrivateKey(generatedPrivateKey);
        client.startServer();
    }
```

And I am calling it from the main method:

```
try {
            showClient();
            ss=new ServerSocket(1201);// server port
            s=ss.accept();// accept conx
            din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            while(!msgin.equals("exit")){
                msgin=din.readUTF();
                msg_area.setText(msg_area.getText().trim()+"\n User 2: "+msgin); //send msg
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error" + e);
   }
```

On the other end this is the method being called:

```
public static void startServer(){
        try{
            s =new Socket("127.0.0.1",1201);// local ip address of user 2 
            din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            String msgin="";

            while(!msgin.equals("exit")){

                msgin=din.readUTF();
                msg_area.setText(msg_area.getText().trim()+"\n User 1: "+msgin);

            }  
        }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error" + e);
        }
    }
```

The error is "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused".

Note: When running each class alone I am calling the same method (startServer()) and the connection is established.

Comment: Wait -- you're starting both the server and the client (and the relative Swing GUI's) on the same thread?

Comment: Only because I want to pass a generated value between the 2 JFrames.

Comment: Shouldn't the "generated value" be passed via the socket connection?

Comment: The key type is PublicKey and if I want to pass it there is no write(publicKey) method available. Could you make it clear how to pass such value?

Comment: First please clarify for me -- are the two "JFrames" the server JFrame and the client JFrame? Is the information that you wish to pass information that should be sent via the socket? This question looks to be a possible [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where you ask how to do "X" when the best solution is to do "Y", a completely different approach.

Comment: Also your code runs afoul of Swing threading rules in a big way.

Comment: 1.Yes, the two JFrames are the server and the client. 
2.I want to pass a generated public and private key so I could encrypt and decrypt on both sides.

Comment: Then this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and yes your approach is to be blunt, completely wrong. You should be starting your two GUI's separately, in separate JVM's, the connection should be via socket only. You will want to also read [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to see why your current code is also not safe for Swing threading. Also read any decent OOPs book to help you get rid of all those static modifiers. Bottom line, start over, and re-think this from first principles.

Comment: Okay, Thank you.